# Swift Dynamically created UILabel shows up twice

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have written a custom graph UIView subclass, and I use it to graph some basic data, and insert some user-defined data. As a final step, I'd like to add a UILabel on top of the graph with the user-defined data-point called out.

I highlight the point, and then create and add the UILabel:

```
if(graphPoints[i] == highlightPoint){
            var point2 = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
            point2.x -= 8.0/2
            point2.y -= 8.0/2
            let circle2 = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:
                CGRect(origin: point2,
                    size: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0)))
            highlightColor.setFill()
            highlightColor.setStroke()
            circle2.fill()
            let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:
                CGRect(origin: point,
                    size: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)))
            UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
            UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()

            circle.fill()
            var pointLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
            pointLabel.text = "Point = \(graphPoints[i])"
            pointLabel.frame = CGRectMake(point2.x, point2.y, 100, 50)
            self.addSubview(pointLabel)
        } else {
            let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:
                CGRect(origin: point,
                    size: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)))
            UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
            UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()
            circle.fill()

        }
```

This looks like it should work, but the UILabel is added twice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this if statement happening somewhere that's ongoing?

Comment: The if statement is in the drawRect function where the graph is drawn. I iterate through the points in graphPoints and highlight the point added by the user. The highlighting works perfectly, and only the one datapoint is highlighted (has a red circle drawn around the white circle). But the UILabel shows up twice, in two different locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is probably in `drawRect`. You're doing subview-adding in `drawRect` which is incorrect. `drawRect` gets called at least twice as the view appears, and perhaps many times after that.

You should be overriding some early lifecycle method, like `awakeFromNib()` or the constructor. In that, construct your label and add it as a child view. This way the `addSubView()` happens *once* as it should. The label will be invisible having no contents, so don't worry about that.

In `drawRect`, just update all the necessary attributes of the label including the `frame`.

If you find you're actually needing lots of text "labels" that come and go, different quantity for every graph, you don't really want `UILabel`s as subviews after all. Consider directly drawing text on screen with `someString.drawAtPoint(...)`

Comment: Two comments: (1) the more "correct" place to update the label's `frame` is in `layoutSubviews`, not `drawRect`, although in my experience either will work fine.

Comment: (2) If you draw text using `drawAtPoint`, etc., visually disabled users won't be able to access your content with VoiceOver unless you also implement the accessibility methods. Easier to just use labels.

Comment: Agreed. For (1), it makes the code a little awkward because the location has to be recalculated. For (2) accessibility for a complex display such as a graph begs a larger question, and if you were to undertake that effort, it seems to make more sense to adopt the accessibility protocol from scratch to describe the whole graph, not just a label (whose location is as important as its text content).